# How to access nested JSON properties using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

The following code block returns a TypeScript error.

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type '{ id: string; path: string;
>   basename: string; createdOn: string; modifiedOn: string; content:
>   string; }'.

Square brackets work fine in JavaScript (or using `//@ts-ignore`).

What is the right way of doing this in TypeScript?

```js
export interface Data {
  [key: string]: {
    id: string
    path: string
    basename: string
    createdOn: string
    modifiedOn: string
    content: string
  }
}

const data = _data as Data // _data is JSON

for (let item in data) {
  for (let property in data[item]) {
    console.log(property)
    if (["createdOn", "modifiedOn"].includes(property)) {
      data[item][property] = new Date(data[item][property])
    }
  }
}
```

Here’s what the JSON of `_data` looks like.

```
{
  "readme": {
    "id": "3905d7917f2b3429490b01cfb60d8f5b",
    "path": "README.md",
    "basename": "README.md",
    "createdOn": "2020-02-26T12:29:26.181Z",
    "modifiedOn": "2020-02-26T12:29:26.181Z",
    "content": "<!--\nTitle: Privacy guides\nDescription: Privacy guides will be published shortly...\n-->\n\n# Privacy guides\n\nPrivacy guides will be published shortly...\n"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: So you want to access/edit createdOn and modifiedOn for each item inside your data array?

Comment: @r3dst0rm Thanks for your help. Added what the JSON looks like to the questions. I wish to iterate through the nested properties of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is two fold:

1. `property` has a `string` type, instead of being known as a key in the nested object
2. `data[item][property] = new Date(...)` will return an error anyway, because your nested object only expect string as values

Since using `.includes()` or `.indexOf()` does not narrow the type properly, you will have to create a function that basically returns the correct keys. This serves as a *type guard* that will return the correct types from a union type:

```
function hasPossibleDateAsValue(value: string): value is 'createdOn' | 'modifiedOn' {
  return ["createdOn", "modifiedOn"].includes(value);
}
```

Then, you can do this without TypeScript throwing an error/warning:

```
for (let item in data) {
  for (let property in data[item]) {
    if (hasPossibleDateAsValue(property)) {
      data[item][property] = new Date(data[item][property]);
    }
  }
}
```

[See proof-of-concept on TypeScript playround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEUxkzgG8BYAKDjgG0BrYATwC44BnGKZAcwF02FajUQATNp25IeAbioi4YIgAsJXXnOE0ARpnbAkmALbA1U2fJrYowIsFEB5JGd5wAPgTuaFRiKIToCPZOLtLunqjeItgQKAYwoRbCAL6ayVRUosDYADaYNnAAbvlwokSYbITEmlToAK5I2DAIsXDKegAKEOzsCNo5wFXAAILsAGqYOXXAABTFU6Yc6tIAlGzz04jscADk1raojkg74Tu+-oHBx2SWNjB1UEh0AET7dkfPADRwz+cBQR8+AA6ZBZEAOdBzSbTFZwACEAF4EXAALQARjSGUo6GgcBmA3gCFQRkQTzKxFhQhoOKgeIJiigEDAaBgTFJpXKtCJwCMfEplhoATx7XYXR6fQGQ1GEwWMzAjOZsCYK35WhE5MwXOJfFo8qZLKYfDgyKQwAA7hFZhqtTydXrFay+VEaOkUlRkkA).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help... so the issue isn’t actually in accessing nested properties but rather in how to work with or around the limitations of `includes`.

Comment: @sunknudsen That is correct. Typescript cannot perform typeguards using includes or indexOf. Anyway, I have updated my answer so that it’s using `includes()` again. It doesn’t matter if you use that or `indexOf()`.